# How to show more than one table row on click

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have 5 rows accompanied with a display button from when clicked I would like to display two of the hidden rows at a time. I would then like the display button to become disabled once the last 2 rows have been displayed.

This question is very similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38936561/how-to-load-more-than-one-div-at-a-time) question except I cannot use the answer because the display:block css alters the data and styling within the row.

```
<p><a href="#" id="display">Display More</a></p>

<table>
 <tr class="showfirstRow">
  <th>First Name</th>
  <th>Last Name</th>
</tr>
 <tr class="secondRow">
  <td>Peter</td>
  <td>Griffin</td>
</tr>
<tr class="thirdRow">
  <td>Lois</td>
  <td>Griffin</td>
</tr>
<tr class="fourthRow">
 <td>Meg</td>
 <td>Griffin</td>
</tr>
<tr class="fithRow">
 <td>Stewie</td>
 <td>Griffin</td>
</tr>
</table>


$("#display").click(function() {
// show the next hidden div.group, then disable the display button once all rows have been displayed
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Added a `hidden` class to use for hide elements.

You can find the next X elements that are hidden inside the table (using `slice(0,2)`, you can use there any number you would like), remove the `hidden` class of them, and if there are no more hidden elements inside the table - add the `hidden` class to the button you just clicked (to hide it).

Here is an example:

```js
$("#display").click(function() {
  $('#tblWithHiddenRows .hidden').slice(0, 2).removeClass('hidden');
  if ($('#tblWithHiddenRows .hidden').length == 0) {
    $(this).addClass('hidden');
  }
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><a href="#" id="display">Display More</a></p>

<table id="tblWithHiddenRows">
 <tr class="hiddenfirstRow">
  <th>First Name</th>
  <th>Last Name</th>
</tr>
 <tr class="secondRow hidden">
  <td>Peter</td>
  <td>Griffin</td>
</tr>
<tr class="thirdRow hidden">
  <td>Lois</td>
  <td>Griffin</td>
</tr>
<tr class="fourthRow hidden">
 <td>Meg</td>
 <td>Griffin</td>
</tr>
<tr class="fithRow hidden">
 <td>Stewie</td>
 <td>Griffin</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

use data-num `<tr class="row secondRow" data-num="1">`

and add this script :

```
num = 1;

$("#display").click(function() {
    row1 = $(".row[data-num='"+num+"']");
  row2 = $(".row[data-num='"+(num+1)+"']");

  if(row1.length>0)
    {
    row1.show();
        row2.show();
  }
  else
    $(this).addClass("disabled");

  num+=2;
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/22xh7bm7/1/

Comment: check the new jsfiddle link